# postpone or regroup triggers on SQL insert

Tags: sql, triggers, h2

Let's have this 2 tables structure:

```
+------------+   +------------+
+ Parent     +   + Child      +
+------------+   +------------+
+ - id       +   + - id       +
+ - label    +   + - idparent +
+ - computed +   + - label    +
+------------+   +------------+
```

On every INSERT or DELETE in the `Child` table, the `computed` field of its parent row in the table `Parent`.

I've created a trigger on insert, update, delete on the `Child` table in order to update the parent's `computed` field.

Pro's: the `computed` field is consistently updated, whatever updates the database

Con's: in case of multiple modifications for the same parent, its `computed` field is updated many times while only one (the last occurrence) should be necessary.

I see the option to solve it this programmatically in the application using the database, without triggers. But there is the risk of inconstancy of the database.

Any suggestion ?

PS: the database is H2, so java is the programming language, even for the triggers, and the SQL set might be different than the one for Oracle, MySQL or SQL server.

Comment: Just calculate the field when needed, using `join`s and other SQL constructs.

Comment: In the real case, the computation is heavy and cannot be done on request.

Comment: . . Doing it during the trigger may be self-defeating.  If it is that heavy, it is going to significantly slow down inserts and updates (and perhaps deletes).

Comment: Hence my question, is it possible to postpone or regroup the execution of triggers by SQL ?

Comment: . . I seriously doubt it.  For integrity of the data, databases need to ensure that triggers are invoked for every data modification that they apply to.  You could instead schedule a job to run say, once per minute or once per hour to do the work.

Comment: The job. This is a good idea. Thanks.